# Accessing methods of subclass within Velocity templates

Tags: java, velocity

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class A{
    private String s;
    public void setS(String s){
       this.s=s;
    }
    public String getS(){
       return this.s;
    }
}
public class B extends A{
    private String s2;
    public void setS2(String s2){
       this.s2=s2;
    }
    public String getS2(){
       return this.s2;
    }
}
public class C{
    private A a;
    public setA(A a){this.a = a;}
    public getA(){return this.a;}
}
```

I created 2 objects:

```
B b = new B();
b.setS("some string");
C c = new C();
c.setA(b);
```

When I load the object into a Velocity template :

```
My Template
$c.a.getS()
```

I get the following output:

```
My Template
$c.a.getS()
```

And not wat it should be:

```
My Template
some string
```

It seems like Velocity doesn't know to load in the template methods inherited from super classes.
Is this true? Or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this problem and I came up with a solution.
To make it work I made the following changes:

1. Make the s property protected instead of private:

   ```
   protected String s;
   ```
2. Make the the getter and setter abstract in the base class A:

   ```
   public abstract void setS(String s);
   public abstract String getS();
   ```
3. Override the abstract methods in the sub class B.